# Existence of an extending measure

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\Omega$ be a nonempty set and $\cal{A}$ be any class of subsets of $\Omega$ including emptyset. Suppose that $\mu:\cal{A}\to R^{+}\cup{+\infty}$ be such a non-zero function that the equality $\mu(\cup_{n \in N}A_n)=\sum_{n \in N}\mu(A_n)$ holds true when $A_n \in \cal{A}$ for each $n \in N$,  $\cup_{n \in N}A_n \in \cal{A}$ and $A_k \cap A_m=\emptyset$ for $1 \le k < m<\infty$. Let $\sigma(\cal{A})$ denotes a minimal sigma algebra generated by $\cal{A}$. Does there exist a  measure $\mu_1$ defined on $\sigma(\cal{A})$ and extending the measure $\mu$?

Comment: Both examples answer to my question in negative. Here naturally arises a question asking whether one can found necessary and sufficient conditions under which the answer to my question is affirmative ("$\cal(A)$ is an algebra"-is a sufficient condition(Charatheodory  theorem)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\Omega=\{1,2,3\}$. Define $\mu(\{1\})=\mu(\{2\})=\mu(\{1,3\})=1$ and $\mu(\{2,3\})=2$ (and $\mu(\varnothing)=0$). Let $\mathcal A$ consist of just the $5$ sets on which I've just defined $\mu$.  This satisfies your hypotheses because the only time disjoint sets in $\mathcal A$ have their union in $\mathcal A$ is when one of the sets is empty.  But there is clearly no extension of $\mu$ to a measure on the generated $\sigma$-algebra.

Answer (score 3):

Andreas beat me to it, but I'll upstage him with an even smaller example.  Let $\Omega=\{a,b\}$, $\mathcal{A}=\{\emptyset, \{a\}, \{a,b\}\}$, and set $\mu(\emptyset)=0$, $\mu(\{a\})=1$, and $\mu(\{a,b\}) = 0$.