# Extending measures counterexample

Tags: measure-theory

Given set X, measure $\mu$ and $\sigma$ algebra $\Sigma$. Say it is contained in a larger $\sigma$ algebra $\Sigma\subset \Sigma'$. Is there a way to extend the measure $\mu$ to $\Sigma'$?

This must have some obvious counterexamples.

Indeed for trivial X we have

[Existence of an extending measure](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/888430/existence-of-an-extending-measure?rq=1)

Let's look at $X=\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $\mu$ the Lebesgue measure. Are there some $\Sigma$ and $\Sigma'$, s.t. $\mu$ does not extend to? I am thinking of making a $\Sigma'$ by adding non-measurable sets to $\Sigma$.

For same X, do you have any measure $\mu$ and $\Sigma$ and $\Sigma'$, s.t. $\mu$ does not extend to? Or maybe a a proof? Or at least suggestion for proof?

If we require translation invariance, then it fails due to Banach-Tarski Paradox.

What are your examples?

Thanks

Comment: If you take $\Sigma'=P(\mathbb{R})$ then you cannot extend the Lebesgue measure $\mu$ from $\Sigma=B(\mathbb{R})$ to $\Sigma'$. This is a rather well-known fact. But its proof involves the axiom of choice, so it would be interesting to look for another example.

Comment: any references for this fact.

Comment: or maybe explain how the Banach-Tarski shows that there can't an extension. Thanks

Comment: Hmm actually I was mistaken: you cannot extend the measure if you want it to remain translation (or isometry) invariant, but if you drop that condition perhaps it is possible.

Comment: With regards to Sergio's comment: whether or not Lebesgue measure can be extended to all subsets of reals is independent of ZFC (if ZFC is consistent). (It is equivalent to the existence of a measurable cardinal below $\mathfrak c$, if I recall correctly.)

Comment: any references for this fact.

Comment: @TKM: I'm not sure, but you should find it in Jech's set theory book.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X=\omega_1$, and suppose $\Sigma$ is the field of countable and cocountable sets, while $\Sigma'$ is the field of all subsets of $\omega_1$, and $\mu$ is $1$ on uncountable sets, while it's $0$ on countable sets.

If $\mu$ extended to $\Sigma'$, then $\omega_1$ would be a real value measurable cardinal. On the other hand, it is well known that such cardinals are weakly inaccessible, which $\omega_1$ isn't. For a proof, see e.g. [Jech's Set Theory](http://books.google.pl/books?id=WTAl997XDb4C&pg=PA132&lpg=PA132).

Note that this question fits quite comfortably within the realm of set theory. Outside set theory, people are usually interested in measures with some more particular properties (for example, invariant or regular measures). In those cases, it is often easier to find examples where extension is impossible, (e.g. using Banach-Tarski paradox, as has been noted).